# if two interface having same method name that time how we achieve multiple inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

```
interface A {
    void method();
}

interface B {
    void method();
}

class c : A,B {
//answer
}
```

Comment: We can't achieve multiple inheritance in C#. Implementing multiple interfaces is not multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement the interfaces explicit.

```
class C : A, B
{
    void A.Method()
    {
        // explicit implementation of interface A
    }

    void B.Method()
    {
        // explicit implementation of interface B
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        // class implementation
    }
}
```

You should be aware of how to invoke the particular methods.

```
var c = new C();

c.Method();       // class implementation
((B)c).Method();  // implementation of B
((A)c).Method();  // implementation of A
```